# How do I address Payment Methods, so I can tweak/CSS it

Tags: css, wordpress

On my shop checkout page for some reason, the **Payment Methods are in black**. Having a black background, this is 'somewhat' unreadable.

The theme dev's provided me with some code to tweak the checkout/cart page, but I can't find this exact part, well, and I am not sure how to address that particular part...

Here's the CSS:

```
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce form .form-row label, .woocommerce-checkout. woocommerce-page form .form-row label {
color: #cdceb9; font-size: 11pt; 
}

.input-text {

.woocommerce-checkout h3 {
color: #cdceb9; font-size: 11pt;
}

.woocommerce-checkout th {
color: #968152; font-size: 11pt;
}

.woocommerce-checkout table.shop_table th, .woocommerce-page table.shop_table th {
color: #968152; font-size: 11pt;
}


.woocommerce-checkout td.product-total,.woocommerce-checkout td.product-subtotal {
color: #cdceb9; font-size: 11pt;
}


.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce table.shop_table tfoot tr td {
color: #cdceb9; font-size: 11pt;
}

Custom css for tweaking cart page
--------------------------------------------------

.woocommerce-cart .woocommerce table.shop_table th, .woocommerce-cart .woocommerce-page table.shop_table th {
color: #968152;
}

.woocommerce-cart .cart_totals tr td strong {
color: #cdceb9;
}

.woocommerce-cart .cart_totals h2 {
color: #cdceb9;
}

.woocommerce-cart td.product-total,.woocommerce-cart td.product-subtotal {
color: #cdceb9;
}

.woocommerce-cart .cart_totals{
color : #cdceb9;
}
```

How would I address the Payment Methods please so I can change the font colour? Its the black text under the 'Your Order' section...

You will need to Add to cart some of the items first, to see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
.payment_methods.methods li label {
    color: white;
}
```

of course you need to change the white color to whatever you wish
for future issue related to css selectors, if you are using chrome go to where the item is and right click then select inspect and you will see the HTML and CSS of the page with focus on the item you want, try to figure out exactly what you need to change then apply it in your css file, and read some about css

for the borders between order details: 
if you want to hide them use:

```
.woocommerce-page table.shop_table tfoot th {
    border-top: none;}
```

if you to only change the color use:

```
.woocommerce-page table.shop_table tfoot th {
    border-top: 1px solid #968152;}
```

or replace #968152 with the color you wish

Comment: Could you also please help me out how to change the ugly white border? And or the dividers?

Comment: Oh thanks for that! What about the border around the payment methods?

Comment: I am using Firebug to Inspect, its just hard for me to recognize, or, address the correct way of a particular element....

Comment: How would I change the bg-color and border of the contact forms, btw?

Comment: I used ".wc_payment_methods payment_methods methods{
    border-top: 1px solid #262619;}" **for the payment methods border**, but it did not work ... :(

Comment: same as the order details border just replace the .woocommerce-page table.shop_table tfoot th with .payment_methods

Comment: nope `.payment_methods {
    border: none;}` did not work :(

Comment: use this .woocommerce-page #payment ul.payment_methods

Comment: and this for the border beneath .woocommerce-page #payment div.form-row

Comment: Now, for the tricky part; the Country dropdown :) how may I style the whole thing so it fits my theme....?

Comment: how do you want to style it ? mention details

Comment: so it basically has the same background color, border and font color of the above forms... I may provide exact # numbers in a minute if needed....

Comment: How may I change the arrow in the Country Dropdown... only need to change that, the border and the tiny white bit on the left... :)